# ADO.NET Entity Framework 4.1 C# DAL create/add objects and access by key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ado.net

I have created a DAL class "FriendManager" encapuslating the access on my entities.

```
public class FriendManager
{
  private readonly FriendsEntities _db;
  public FriendManager()
  {
    _db = new FriendsEntities();
  }

  public void SaveChanges()
  {
    _db.AcceptAllChanges();
  }

  public Guid CreateFriend(string forename, string surname)
  {
    var id = Guid.NewGuid();
    _db.Friends.AddObject(new Friend { Identifier = id, Name = string.Concat(forename, , " ", surname) });
    _db.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);
    return id;
  }

  public void AddFriendsAddress(Guid friendId, string address)
  {
    var friend = GetFriend(friendId);
    friend.Address = address;
    _db.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);
  }

  public Friend GetFriend(Guid id)
  {
    return (from friends in _db.Friends
            where friends.Identifier == id
            select friends).SingleOrDefault();
  }
}
```

Now I want to create a friend in a console application and write the created entry to the command line by accessing it immediately afterwards before calling SaveChanges()!

```
using (var manager = new FriendManager())
{
  bool success = false;
  try
  {
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
      var id = manager.CreateFriend("John", "Fischer");
      manager.AddFriendsAddress(id, "Blue Hole 12, 1234 Atlantic, World");
      var john = manager.GetFriend(id);
      Console.WriteLine("My new friend {0} lives in {1}.", john.Name, john.Address);
      scope.Complete();
    }
    success = true;
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("The following went wrong: {0}", ex.Message);        
  }
  if (success) manager.SaveChanges();
}

Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to exit...");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Now I am getting a PK violation error, because EF is trying to add John twice into my Friends entity! If I do not call "_db.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);" in "CreateFriend" method, then "AddFriendsAddress" fails because John is not found in the Friends entity (return value of "GetFriend" is always NULL)!

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your console application to:

```
using (var manager = new FriendManager())
{
var id = manager.CreateFriend("John", "Fischer");
manager.SaveChanges();
var john = manager.GetFriend(id);
Console.WriteLine("My new friend {0}.", john.Name);
}
```

You should save your data to database first then call it by key.

Comment: what happens if an exception occurs in code after "CreateFriend" and I want to roll back, so prevent "SaveChanges()" before I explicitly say so?

Comment: For that you have to use transactions, you can batch multiple database calls and multiple operations in transaction, if one fails it roles back everything. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738523.aspx . Your main problem is that you can call only persistent objects, object that are stored in database (or similar storage).

Comment: please take a look at my initial post, I have updated it completely!

Comment: Can you provide db structure for the problem so I can recreate it. If I understand it correctly in the end you want to destroy friend if you were unable to create its address?